# How can I remember combination states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having a logic problem with an implementation of combination rules in Javascript.

In short:

- I define which checkboxes cannot be 'on' together with eachother in a JSON object.
- If I click on measure 1 -> measures 7 and 8 get grayed out, this is correct.
- If I click on measure 4 -> measures 8, 9, 10 and 11 get grayed out, this is correct too.
- Now, if I click again on measure 4 -> measure 8 gets active again, but shouldn't be, because the JSON 'rules' state that since measure 1 is still checked, measure 8 must be grayed.

What's a smart way to solve this logic problem? Thanks in advance!

*Basically, how do I remember that clicking 'measure 1' already disabled 'measure 8', so that toggling 'measure 4' won't accidentally re-enable 'measure 8' with 'measure 1' still 'on'?*

All code here: https://gist.github.com/1055968

Interactive: http://jsfiddle.net/gnijholt/58zuR/

Comment: That's a lot of code. Do you expect us to read and understand everything? Can't you reduce the code to the absolute minimum to demonstrate the problem and post it here?

Comment: Agreed, it's a lot of code. Does it help that I added a jsfiddle? Thx..

Comment: Nice error code: `sex - string expected`. What was wrong with `stx`?

Comment: :) That's in code from JSONSelect, which is a library I'm using to 'query' the JSON.

Comment: What's the big deal? Just loop over all the checkboxes and execute the click handlers (again) for all those that are active and selected. Not efficient, but implementable in about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well logically i'd do something like this:

- when you tick a checkbox, you create
  an object which stores the rules that
  are applied.
- when i untick a checkbox, i will
  remove that rule from the memory
  object and before unticking each
  checkboxes i'll go through the memory
  object to see if there are any
  conflicting rules. If there is one
  conflicting rules, i do not gray out
  the checkbox.

I'm trying to implement this.

EDIT - i'v implemented my idea. here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tvs7E/1/

```
function createObjectsWithRules(rulesApplied){
    var presentBlock = {};
    for (var checkboxid in rulesApplied){
      var presentCombos = rulesApplied[checkboxid];
       for(var key in presentCombos) {
           var obj = presentCombos[key];
           for(var prop in obj) {
              var s = obj[prop];
               presentBlock[s] = true;

           }
       }
    }
    return presentBlock;
}

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var rulesApplied= {};
            $('input').change(function() {
                current_cb = this;
                if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                // toggle on

                    console.log("You ticked on " + current_cb.id);
                    combos = JSONSelect.match("." + current_cb.id, combinations);
                    rulesApplied[current_cb.id] = combos;
                    for(var key in combos) {
                        var obj = combos[key];
                        for(var prop in obj) {
                            var s = obj[prop];
                            $('#' + s).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                            console.log("I disable " + obj[prop]);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(rulesApplied);
                    return;
                }
                // toggle off
                console.log("You ticked off " + current_cb.id);
                combos = JSONSelect.match("." + current_cb.id, combinations);
                console.log(combos);
                delete rulesApplied[current_cb.id];
                console.log(rulesApplied);
                presentRules = createObjectsWithRules(rulesApplied);
                console.log(presentRules);

                for(var key in combos) {
                    var obj = combos[key];
                    for(var prop in obj) {
                        var s = obj[prop];
                        if (!presentRules[s]){
                          $('#' + s).removeAttr('disabled');
                          console.log("I enable " + obj[prop]);
                        }          
                    }
                }
                return;
            });
        });
```

Comment: No need to store a rule in memory. The rules are defined in the beginning, and the checkboxes maintain the state. You only need to loop over the checkboxes and implement the rule for those that are active and checked. You're storing redundant data and making life hard for yourself.

Comment: well i just keep trakck of the rules that are applied withouth needing to recheck them. It could be useful if the rules are stored in a way that retrieving them is complex. But your idea is good too! :)

Comment: Works great.. I'm going to try both solutions. Thx a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .change event to this

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/424704/

It does what it did before, only without using empty returns to emulate an if-else.

Then when it is done with the clicked input, it loops through all the input to "re-disable" whatever needs to be disabled.

Only tested it lightly

And I can see that while I was writing this, davin was making the same suggestion in the comments. It's the same thing, just with a code example.